# iPhone app to invest in UK mutual funds

Tags: iphone-app, finance

Looking for an iOS app like the Fidelity or Wealthify ones that support buying and selling UK mutual funds. Fidelity only shows current invested mutual funds but doesn't allow to buy or sell.

Wealthify does not allow me to choose my own mutual funds.

My first priority is too be able to do that on iOS, charges are only a secondary priority but please mention them in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since I asked that question I found one such app.

ii investing - ii is short for Interactive Investor. Minimum investment is £100 per fund. 6% charge.

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind adding enough information to comply with http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality ? Cheers!